# Animate or do a transition from bottom to top in splash screen in xamarin forms?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I am trying to have a background image with the logo at the bottom initially in splash screen. The transition from bottom to center should occur once the splash screen loads in both ios and Android (xamarin forms). Please share your thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Animation Splash screen, please follow the following step. I do one sample in Android.

Firstly, please creating SplashScreen.axml.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <ImageView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
    android:src="@drawable/splash_logo" 
    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Secondly, creating Anim folder in Resource folder, creating bottomtotop.xml animation about translation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">

 <translate 
         android:fromYDelta="100%p"
         android:toYDelta="0"
         android:duration="600"/>

 </set>
```

Thirdly, creating new activity name SplashScreenDemo.cs, using animation. Setting MainLauncher = true.

```
 [Activity(Label = "SplashScreenDemo", MainLauncher = true)]
public class SplashScreenDemo : Activity
{
    ImageView imageView;
    Animation view_animation;
    TextView textview;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.SplashScreen);
        imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
        view_animation = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(this, Resource.Animation.bottomtotop);
        imageView.StartAnimation(view_animation);
        view_animation.AnimationEnd += Rotate_AnimationEnd;
        // Create your application here
    }

    private void Rotate_AnimationEnd(object sender, Animation.AnimationEndEventArgs e)
    {
       // Finish();
        Intent intent;
        intent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity));
        StartActivity(intent);
       
    }
}
```

Comment: this is in android studio... i am asking in xamarin forms for both android and iOS

Comment: @faizal Yes, if you want to use splashscreen, you just do it in different platform(Android and ios).About animation in ios, please take a look:[Core Animation in Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/graphics-animation-ios/core-animation)